# Android Timestamps vs Unix Timestamps

Tags: android, timestamp

sorry I don't have experience with Android. I have been using an app to record IMU data and I need timestamps since epoch in nanoseconds. The app generates cvs file that states

```
Timestamp[nanosec]
379575046451850
379575051336382 ...
```

However, I always have been familiar with the timestamp like this

```
timestamp
1602663595777087900
1602663595795272900
```

Both should be in nanoseconds. I am curious because two independent apps that record data generate timestamp in ns in the same format. How should I interpret the above data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the current epoch time is `1604009999` (10 digits), these might be microseconds (1/1,000,000 second): `379575046451850`, `379575051336382` (39 years ago). And these are nanoseconds (1 billionth of a second): `1602663595777087900`, `1602663595795272900` (16 days ago). Wouldn't be too sure about the format starting with `3795750`, maybe one can interpret them differently. The question doesn't tell what they're supposed to mean and there was no Android 39 years ago. Maybe it's an Excel timestamp?

Comment: Those should be nanoseconds, not microseconds. Thats why I am confused. I have taken the measurements yesterday so it cannot be 39 years ago as well